# Set the extracted text in a column As a Single String in Pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

So I extracted string from an image with 3 columns.
the  extracted text is:
SUBJECT GRADE FINALGRADE CREDITS
ADVANCED CALCULUS 1  1.54 A 3
I want to put a separator between these items that it should look like this:
SUBJECT, GRADE, FINALGRADE, CREDITS
ADVANCED CALCULUS 1,  1.54, A, 3

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the image with us?

Comment: heres a close example https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F15f8U.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F436786%2Fsubheader-for-table-in-latex&tbnid=G3lyjTFTuM7haM&vet=1&docid=Ug6up-qEU4dEqM&w=654&h=404&itg=1&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve the solution by two-steps.

- 1. Specify the starting keyword.
- 2. Split the line using space as the separator.

If we look at the provided example from the comment:

[image]

We don't need any image-preprocessing, since there is no artifact in the image.

Assume I want to separate the row starting with "state" with comma.

- 1. Specify the starting keyword:

     - ```py
       start_word = line.split(" ")[0]
       ```
- 2. Split the line using space as the separator:

     - ```py
       if start_word == "state":
           line = line.split(" ")
       ```

Now for each word in the line, we can add comma to the end

```py
for word in line:
    result += word + ", "
```

But we need to remove the last two characters, otherwise it will end "2000, "

```py
result = result[:-2]
print(result)
```

Result:

```py
state, 1983, 1987, 1988, 1993, 1994, 1999, 2000
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("15f8U.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255,
                            cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)

txt = txt.split("\n")
result = ""

for line in txt:
    start_word = line.split(" ")[0]
    if start_word == "state":
        line = line.split(" ")
        for word in line:
            result += word + ", "
        result = result[:-2]
        print(result)
        continue
    if line != '' or line != "":
        print(line)
```

Result:

```
Table 1: WAGE SAMPLE STATISTICS, by year and state (1983-2000)
 
 
Logged mean wages
in year
 
 
 
state, 1983, 1987, 1988, 1993, 1994, 1999, 2000
Andhra Pradesh 5.17 5.49 5.53 6.28 6.24 5.77 5.80
Gujarat 9 6.04 5.92 6.64 6.58 6.09 6.04
Haryana 12 6.25 6.43 6.80 6.60 6.54 6.74
Manipur 54 6.31 6.73 7.15 7.09 6.90 6.83
Orissa 5.24 5.90 5.96 6.16 6.26 5.57 5.58
Tamil Nadu 5.19 5.67 5.68 6.31 633 6.02 5.97
Uttar Pradesh 5.55 6.06 3 6.61 2 6.00 6.07
Mizoram 6.43 5.44 6.03 681 6.76 8 7
```

Comment: wowww you saved me! im developing a transcript of records reader so i'm having quite a hard time figuring out what to do but i'll apply this thank you